ReactDOMClient is not defined
I am trying to get started with ReactJS and I have watched a beginners Pluralsight course.  I seem to be falling at the first hurdle followin what the tutor is doing.  Here is my HTML (index.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple React app no JSS</title>
    <script src="index.js" ></script>
    <script type="module">
        import React from
        "https://esm.sh/react@19.0.0-beta-04b058868c-20240508/?dev"

        import ReactDOMClient from
        "https://esm.sh/react-dom@19.0.0-beta-04b058868c-20240508/client/?dev"
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>

Here is my Javascript (index.js):
window.onload = () => {
    const rootElement=document.getElementById("root");
    const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(rootElement);
    const ints = [1,2,3]
    const childrenElements = [];
    childrenElements.push(
        React.createElement("li", { key:ints[0] }, ints[0])
    );
    childrenElements.push(
        React.createElement("li", { key:ints[1] }, ints[1])
    );
    childrenElements.push(
        React.createElement("li", { key:ints[2] }, ints[2])
    );
    root.render(childrenElements);
}

Nothing is displayed, which is not the case for the tutor.  If I inspect console after pressing F12, then I see this:

If I manually browse (using a web browser) to https://esm.sh/react@19.0.0-beta-04b058868c-20240508/?dev or https://esm.sh/react-dom@19.0.0-beta-04b058868c-20240508/client/?dev then I see content so I beliece they are valid.

The window.onload runs before the module is loaded.
Easiest way to get this working is to move you onload to a script with type module at the end of your body so it's called after everything has loaded


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple React app no JSS</title>
       
    <script type="module">
      import React from "https://esm.sh/react@19.0.0-beta-04b058868c-20240508/?dev"
      import ReactDOMClient from "https://esm.sh/react-dom@19.0.0-beta-04b058868c-20240508/client/?dev"
  
      window.React = React;
      window.ReactDOMClient = ReactDOMClient;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module">
        const rootElement=document.getElementById("root");
        const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(rootElement);
        const ints = [1,2,3]
        const childrenElements = [];
        childrenElements.push(
            React.createElement("li", { key:ints[0] }, ints[0])
        );
        childrenElements.push(
            React.createElement("li", { key:ints[1] }, ints[1])
        );
        childrenElements.push(
            React.createElement("li", { key:ints[2] }, ints[2])
        );
        root.render(childrenElements);
    </script>
</body>




"You need a babel loader to use import" - no, you don't. Just adding type="module" to the script in the body is sufficient.

you can import React and ReactDOMClient directly to index.js
Don't forget to set type="module" for
<script type="module" src="index.js" ></script>

The problem is the reference to ReactDomClient, it should be ReactDom
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement)
and the script block in the index.html:
<script
  crossorigin
  src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
></script>
<script
  crossorigin
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
></script>

